# Conversion factor between different Landsats?

Tags: measurements, remote-sensing, satellites

I have collected data (spectral bands) from Landsat 4-5 and Landsat 8. I was calculating NDVI when I noticed that the two Landsats have different band numbers designated as Red and Near Infra Red (needed for NDVI calculation).

When I checked the wavelengths associated with these bands at [Landsat Band Description](http://landsat.usgs.gov/band_designations_landsat_satellites.php) I noticed that the wavelengths also differ a bit.

For example: I used bands 3 and 4 (Red & Near Infra Red) from Landsat 4-5 and bands 4 and 5 (Red and Near Infra Red) from Landsat 8 for NDVI calculation, but the wavelength range of band 3 in Landsat 4-5 is not exactly the same as of band 4 in Landsat 8.

Is there any way to convert things so that they are same and comparable. I got big variances between NDVI values from the two satellites and have the idea that's because the wavelengths differ.

Comment: Hi, did you atmospherically correct the bands?

Comment: No, I didnt perform any corrections